# Pass Timezone arguments into gitlab service

Tags: docker, selenium, gitlab, yaml

I currently run tests on a shared gitlab runner, and selenium-standalone/chrome container to run my UI tests. However, I need to run the tests on an INDIAN timezone but the container by default uses UTC time. I am able to change the TZ using the following docker command locally,

```
docker run -e "TZ=Asia/Kolkata" -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:latest
```

I want to do something similar on my gitlab yaml file as well

```
services:
- name: selenium/standalone-chrome
  entrypoint: ["opt/bin/entry_point.sh"]
  command: ['-e', 'TZ=Asia/Kolkata']
```

However, the above code does not seem to work. How can this be done?